# How to find a string in Woocommerce hook 'woocommerce_email_order_details'

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to find (and to modify) a customized string in transactional emails as the one made with */woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-processing-order.php*

In that email we have a customized text under the salutation *(Hi, surname)* and the first row of email text.

We are sure that that customized text is coming from **'woocommerce_email_order_details'** hook

How to edit and modify that hook?

Comment: If you are sure about the hook, search your theme files based on the hook through a code editor program. You can then adjust the found result or add it to your question. It is important to be able to overwrite the existing text since it is an action hook versus a fitler hook.  Adding an action hook will add new content to the existing one, not overwrite the existing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure about it being the right hook, the way you change is by locating the `functions.php` file in your child theme (are you using a [child theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/)?), and adding the following code to the bottom.
You can modify the parameters in the body of the modifyEmailText function.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'modifyEmailText', 10, 4 );  

function modifyEmailText($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email){
    // modify $plain_text if needed...
}
```

There are probably better ways to do this.  [Here is a guide to customizing WC order emails](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-customize-woocommerce-order-emails/).

If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).